# Only some unicode characters work with ncurses

Tags: ncurses, widechar

I'm using ncurses 6.3, installed on OSX 12.0.1. My program is:

```cpp
#define NCURSES_WIDECHAR 1

#include <locale.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  initscr();
  // prints fine. Even the red heart, which is multiple code-points.
  addwstr(L"❤️\n");
  // doesn't print the check mark. Interesting...
  addwstr(L"️✅");
  refresh();
  getch();
  endwin();

  // Prints fine.
  printf("%ls\n", L"✅");

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug in ncurses, or much more likely I am misusing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`U+2705` was added to Unicode in [2010](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2705), which makes it a little old, but `wcwidth` returns -1, making ncurses believe it is nonprinting.  I can see this in a debug trace using the ncurses test program (using mouse to select/highlight the missing character's position),

[image: ncurses test-program]

which has this chunk:

```
PUTC 0x20
PutAttrChar({{ {-1:\u2705} }}) at (2, 25)
forced to blank
PUTC 0x20
```

The part in `{{`..`}}` comes from a trace function (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/ec11aef4715d52e8214d904eaa39d1cda3849333/ncurses/trace/lib_traceatr.c#L327)) using `_nc_wacs_width`, which in turn is either a [macro](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/ec11aef4715d52e8214d904eaa39d1cda3849333/ncurses/curses.priv.h#L1865) calling `wcwidth` directly, or a [function](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/ec11aef4715d52e8214d904eaa39d1cda3849333/ncurses/tinfo/lib_acs.c#L321) calling [`wcwidth`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcwidth.html).  Either way, it doesn't appear to be a bug in ncurses.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into wcwidth and see if other implementations do the right thing with ✅.

And thank you so much for maintaining ncurses!